# question about forking in Linux

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I'm currently learning operating systems, I have this snippet of the code but I receive infinite loop of recursive calls, all I want is to create some son's and to calculate fibonacci(with small numbers), I can't understand why sons can't finish at all, thanks in advance:

```
int fibonaci(int n) {
    if(n < 2){
        return n;
    } 
    return fibonaci(n - 1) + fibonaci(n - 2);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

        //some checkings, and variables

    for (i = 0; i < argc; ++i) {
        son_pid = fork();
        if (son_pid == 0) {
            fibonaci(var); //var is some finite variable
            break;
        } 
    }
        if(son_pid != 0){
                while(wait(&status) != -1){}
        }
        return 0;
}
```

#### edited

all checkings were done, problem is with logic!!!

Comment: Where are the other usages of `status`?

Comment: Add `printf("%d\n", var);` before the first call to `fibonaci` - validate that the value you pass really is a small integer and not the string I suspect it may be.

Comment: I checked both values, its ok

Comment: i compiled your code, with a `printf("fibonacci result for %d is %d", var, fibonaci(var));` and it display the correct result. What is your problem ?

Comment: try to set some variable inside function fibonace, it must be infinite loop!

Comment: `all checkings were done` - move zig, for great justice!

Comment: How large is val? The values greater than 20 can took about several hours since it's a exponential algorithm. Anyway with 32-bit integers you cannot calculate the Fibonacci number for n > 42.

Comment: not quite correct -- most desktops can run this program to calculate fib(20) in under a second, and it won't overflow a 32-bit int until n >= 47, but correct in spirit.  My desktop can run this program in about 2 seconds to calculate fibonacci(40), and it doubles for each larger n as expected...

Comment: fibonacci returns a value, which is ignored.  The "while (...){}" is your infinite loop.

Comment: `wait()` will hang your program to next incoming signal if there is no alive childs left. How you determined " infinite loop of recursive calls" ? And how many childs lefts hanging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the solution, but try to put a return 0 instead of the break;

I do believe that the problem is in the forking/treating son vs parent code. I can't see why you put the break there. After calculating the fibonacci, the son should return. The break may be having some unwanted results.

Comment: `break` causes the loop to exit, going on to the `if` after the loop, which will be false in the child, and so just `return 0;`.  So changing the break as you suggest will have no effect.

Comment: yes, i believe you're right. I rarely use break other than in switch cases. But the code is somehow wierd, begining with the use of argc on the for cicle (argv would make a little more sense, but that should not cause infinite loop anyway), and the pre-increment of i. The recursion is quite plain, so no problems there, and the wait should also work.

Answer (score 0):

The ["default behavior"](http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait) of `wait()` is to return immediately with `-1` if it has no children that can be killed, as you expected:

> **wait()**: on success, returns the process ID of the terminated child; on error, -1 is returned.

and

> **ECHILD** (for **wait()**) The calling process does not have any unwaited-for children.

My quick test confirms that the program works.  However, there could be some variation in `wait()` behavior.

On the bright side, you know how many children you `fork()`'d (`argc` many).  Therefore, an arguably more correct version of the `wait()` loop is:

```
if (son_pid) {
    int i, status;
    for (i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        wait(&status);
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.